# What is the best way to force usage of org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicUnadvisedInterceptor?

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I have a highly-concurrent Spring-based web application, where each request spawns hundreds of threads that each want access to singleton beans and request-scoped beans.  We're seeing bottlenecks throughout Spring's code because of competing accesses to ConcurrentHashMap, as well as generally high cpu overhead when invoking the proxied methods.

An experiment shows that hard-coding CglibAopProxy.getCallbacks() to use DynamicUnadvisedInterceptor rather than DynamicAdvisedInterceptor reduced cpu usage and latency substantially.  Our application has exactly zero advised beans and there is no known downside to disabling advice.

My experiment involved:

1. Overriding CglibAopProxy by copying it into an application-owned jar, placed on the classpath before the spring jar.  This forced the JVM to pick up my class.
2. Modified code to insert the target interceptor twice, rather than aop followed by target.  [location](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/d54e101f00e869573ec4cdcc4b02921645154cb2/spring-aop/src/main/java/org/springframework/aop/framework/CglibAopProxy.java#L313-L314)
3. Tested application on a development platform.

I expected small performance gains plus a broken application, but I got large gains and a seemingly-fine application.

What is the best way to implement this?  Ideally without overriding core Spring classes.  :)

**EDIT:** every proxied bean in Spring is advised, thanks to [Spring itself](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-aop/src/main/java/org/springframework/aop/scope/ScopedProxyFactoryBean.java#L109).  There is therefore no supported way to eliminate the overhead from a proxied bean.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Firstly, thanks for this intriguing question. I cannot debug prose, however. Therefore, please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A GitHub project would be great. Thank you. P.S.: If you have problems with Spring AOP proxies, did you consider using native AspectJ instead? P.P.S.: If each request spawns hundreds of threads, I hope you are talking about virtual threads and not native ones. 

Comment: Another question is why your beans/components, if not advised by anything, would be proxied at all.

Comment: Thank you!  I was really hoping for a configuration option somewhere to achieve the specific change, i.e. switch to DynamicUnadvisedInterceptor.  There's no way to reproduce our particular situation in a minimal project, etc. plus there's nothing specifically broken to reproduce.

>>Another question is why your beans/components, if not advised by anything, would be proxied at all.
This is an interesting question, and if answered, could be the solution I'm looking for.  What configuration settings tell Spring to use DynamicAdvisedInterceptor even when the beans are not advised?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding - the point I'm trying to make is that reproducing our behavior isn't required for someone to (hopefully) provide a link to relevant Spring documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Spring 6.1 contains an optimization that captures 98% of the observed performance difference between DynamicUnadvisedInterceptor and DynamicAdvisedInterceptor, when the following are true:

1. There are no method-specific Advisors applied to the beans
2. The beans are advised for other reasons, for example request-scoped singletons which are advised under-the-covers.

For reference, the relevant commit is https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/89e7174cc4c1cbb06da875e889bb57d0f8e86cf0.